# How to install p7zip-full in python docker

Tags: docker

I am creating python:2.7-alpine docker with p7zip-full.

But when I build docker I get this error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  p7zip-full (missing):
    required by: world[p7zip-full]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update --no-cache bind-tools curl coreutils perl bash sudo p7zip-full' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is my code:

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

MAINTAINER QuangVu

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app


RUN apk add --no-cache python && \
    python -m ensurepip && \
    rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    rm -r /root/.cache

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN apk add --update --no-cache bind-tools curl coreutils perl bash sudo p7zip-full

CMD ["python","test.py"]
```

How can I install p7zip-full successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apk search p7zip` in the container which based on python:2.7-alpine:

```
/ # apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.9.4-10-g358e034123 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main]
v3.9.4-9-g2577e96215 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community]
OK: 9771 distinct packages available
/ # apk search p7zip-full
/ # apk search p7zip
p7zip-doc-16.02-r3
p7zip-16.02-r3
```

So, only `p7zip` in apk repo, please use next instead:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache p7zip
```